# Incorrect answer in operator overloading

Tags: c++

I have just been learning about operator overloading and I wanted to try to make an object that represented a complex number. I wrote the following:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class complexNumber
{
    public:
        double re, im;
        complexNumber(){}
        complexNumber(double a, double b)
        {
            re = a;
            im = b;
        }
        complexNumber operator+ (complexNumber b)
        {
            complexNumber c;
            c.re = re + b.re;
            c.im = im + b.im;
        }
        complexNumber operator- (complexNumber b)
        {
            complexNumber c;
            c.re = re - b.re;
            c.im = im - b.im;
        }
};

int main()
{
    complexNumber a(1,2);
    complexNumber b(4,6);
    complexNumber c;
    complexNumber d;

    c = a + b;
    d = a - b;

    cout << c.re << " + " << c.im << "i" << endl;
    cout << d.re << " + " << d.im << "i" << endl;
}
```

And I got the result:

2.44156e+253 + 6.95225e-308i

2.44156e+253 + 6.95225e-308i

Any ideas of where I am going wrong here.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: juanchopanza's now-deleted answer already said this, but I think it's worth repeating: The default (parameterless) constructor is awful, as it leaves members uninitialized. At least initialize them via `complexNumber() : re(), im() {}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to return a value from your functions.  Is your compiler not warning you of this?

Comment: +1 Make compiler writers happy: Heed their warnings! They spent time putting them in their compilers!